PCA with Time Series and Leakage
I have the following code for a simple statistical factor model with PCA and moving window for time series data:
def moving_window_PCA(X):
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=10)
error_start = np.inf
prediction = None
testset = None
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    
    train, test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]

    pca = PCA(n_components = 10)
    X_fitted = pca.fit_transform(train)

    linreg = LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(X_fitted, train)

    pred = pca.transform(test)
    pred = linreg.predict(pred)
    error = mean_squared_error(test, pred)

    if error <= error_start:
        prediction = pred
        testset = test
return prediction, testset

It fits my data so well that I know it must be leaking. But I can't see where in the code the leakage is happening. Is there fundamental knowledge about PCA that I'm missing? I'm trying to fit a model to 10 time series. Even when I decrease n_components and use Ridge instead of LinearRegression, I still get results that are far too good to be true.
